# Would i use a switch or ternary for image/icon switching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a dynamic list of thumbnails, some are images, others need to be represented with icons. What i want, is based on the contentType, to show either an image, or an icon.

```
  const testSwitch = (item) => {
    switch(item.contentType){
      case image/jpeg:
        <img src={item.url} />
      case image/tiff:
        <img src={item.url} />
      case image/png:
        <img src={item.url} />
      case image/bmp:
        <img src={item.url} />
      case text/plain:
        <TextSnippetIcon  />
      case video/mp4:
        <VideoFileIcon  />
      case audio/mpeg:
        <AudioFileIcon  />
      case application/pdf:
        <PictureAsPdfIcon  />
    }
  }

{attachmentInfo.map((item,index) => {
    return(
        <Grid container lg={3} key={index}>
            {() => testSwitch(item)}
            {/* {item.contentType == 'image/jpeg' || "image/png" ? <img src={item.url} /> : 
                <TextSnippetIcon />} */}
        </Grid>
    )
})}
```

So i figured that if i was inside of a map loop, I would run a function (testSwitch), and pass it the item, which should give it all the properties of said item, including item.contentType.Then i figured if i use that to base the switch off, I could generate an image or an icon based off that IE (item.contentType == audio.mpeg) results in an AudioFileIcon. But it doesnt seem to be working the way i expect. Im guessing its either how i call the function inside the loop (call it to auto run i figured, as there is no click event to run it so switchTest()), or the issuee is my lack of understanding switch cases, IE am i calling contentType correctly? The commented line works, but it only switches betweeen an image and a textIcon, not ideal when theres like 10 different icon types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the return statements in your function. Add it for each of the cases eg.

```
case application/pdf:
     return <PictureAsPdfIcon  />
```

And to render it simply do `{testSwitch(item)}`

Comment: Changed the above. Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: image is not defined. Tried it with item inside the switch, and item.contentType

Comment: Wrap your cases in quotation marks eg: `case 'image/jpeg'`